# Application Deployment question

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I'm new to deploying for 2 OS, lets say for example I want to deploy to Leopard and Snow Leopard. Both have simple code differences. What is the most common way of doing this?
- Make 2 targets, one with base sdk 10.5 and the other to 10.6?
- Another way?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make you target SDK 10.6 and your Mac OS X deployment target 10.5, then just code for 10.5.

Comment: Excellent that sounds easy, but what about code that works only for 10.6 and not for 10.5, do I need to make a compiler check?

Comment: One thing you can do is set the base sdk to 10.5 and see what doesn't compile, and what new warnings show up